# sweet alert is stoping my data insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sweetalert

i am working on web-form where simple insertion is being place. i write a JS block to show success popup with the help of sweet alert. onclientclick i calling java script. javascript block work fine but no data insert into database.
that my java script code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function massege() {
        swal({
            title: 'Congratulation!',
            text: 'Your Data has been saved',
            type: 'success',
            confirmButtonText: 'ok'
        },
        function(){
            window.location.href = 'RegisterRoute.aspx';
        });
    }
</script>
```

here my button code

```
   <asp:Button ID="id" type="submit" runat="server" CssClass="btn pull-right" Text="Register Route" OnClick="RouteRegistration_Click" OnClientClick="massege(); return false"  />
```

i had try it with another way like below

```
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "success", "massege();", true);
```

but from this method popup don't show. any idea what going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return false may be preventing to submit the request. Remove return false from below line and try. Attach the click event as..
OnclientClick="message();"

```
<asp:Button ID="RouteRegistration" type="submit" runat="server" CssClass="btn pull-right" Text="Register Route" OnClick="RouteRegistration_Click" OnClientClick="massege();" />
```